# How the Postmaster@domain address works

Tags: exchange, smtp, smarthost, email

I'm very new to Exchange (in fact, an apprentice and studying it at the moment) and am wondering how the Postmaster@domain.com address works. An example:

A smarthost configured with one mailbox, Postmaster@serverfault.com, with an *@serverfault.com  alias so, my understanding, all mail sent to *@serverfault.com is SMTP forwarded onto the postmaster@serverfault.com address.

But what happens now? Does Exchange have a master mailbox Postmaster, that receives all this mail and just dishes it out to the correct mailbox? Or is what I just wrote a pile of garbage!

So I'm a little confused. On the Smart Host - there is SMTP forwarding to forward all SMTP to IP Address x.x.x.x which is active for a mailbox on the smarthost called Postmaster@domain.co.uk with an alias of *@domain.co.uk? How is this working exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The postmaster address is an [RFC mandated specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmaster_%28computing%29).  Essentially every e-mail domain on the planet should have one as a best practice.  Typically the e-mail that is received at this address is sent or shared with the mailserver administrator.

Typically Exchange forwards all postmaster e-mail to whatever address is setup as the server administrator.  In addition as you pointed out the wildcard prefix is indeed a catch all e-mail address.  This means that all e-mail is received by default regardless of whether or not the mailbox exists or not.  You may or may not want to disable this so that e-mail sent to the wrong user is rejected (a.k.a. Bounced).

Comment: Sorry - but how then does it work exactly - if all my mail is being forwarded by the smarthost to postmaster?

Comment: The address is provided so people outside of your domain can send an email to the postmaster, like you have a user who is spamming me, etc. although abuse@ is normally reserved for that.  If you have a real mailbox defined mail will be delivered to the mailbox, the *@domain is only used if no matching mailbox is found.

Comment: So I'm a little confused. On the Smart Host - there is SMTP forwarding to forward all SMTP to IP Address x.x.x.x which is active for a mailbox on the smarthost called Postmaster@domain.co.uk with an alias of *@domain.co.uk? How is this working exactly?

Comment: You're getting to the point where you need to grab a book or other resource.  You have asked about three or four different topics that would be found in a typical Exchange Admin book.

Comment: It's not just best practice. The postmaster address is **mandatory**, i.e. every MTA **MUST** provide a postmaster address to be compliant.

Comment: Would it be possible for a brief explanation?

Comment: @TheD The brief explanation is the RFC.  Refer to (i.e. "Read in their entirety") [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) and [RFC 2142](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt)